# Execute code inside an if(0) block

Tags: c, linux, if-statement

A challenge for all the C experts out there:
On a linux machine, you have an already compiled C program, and you are given its source code:

```
...  
char buffer[20];  
int code;  
gets(buffer);  
if(code==1234) ...  
...  
...  
if(0) func();
```

You don't posses root privileges and the program is read-only. Find a way to execute func. I am certain this is possible, so please don't post any "It isn't possible" answers.
Good luck!

Comment: I suppose it may be possible, but you'd need to specify more information (one example: the compiler and options used to build the program - a GCC build with any level of optimization will not even have a call to `func()` in the program image due to dead code elimination).

Comment: -1 and F to your professor/TA. This question is utter nonsense.

Comment: @R.. I agree this does not teach serious compiler optimization techniques, but I would say that that is not the point at all. The entire purpose of assignments like these is to teach students the problems with unchecked buffer overflows, as well as an understanding of what the stack actually looks like in memory. Both are very useful topics, and probably the next step in the assignment is calling a function that is not even referenced by the code in question. See: [BufBomb](http://cgi2.cs.rpi.edu/~hollingd/comporg-2004s/hw/hw4.html) (a common CS class assignment).

Comment: Well using an `if (0)` is not the way to teach it. They could have instead used `printf("%d\n", code);` and asked how it produces nonzero output. But again, any reasonable compiler would simply optimize out `code` and pass an immediate 0 directly to `printf`...

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the unchecked buffer overflow that is waiting to happen with `gets(buffer);` and an understanding of what the stack looks like.

Answer (score 3):

It may or may not be possible. If there are no other references to func(), the compiler may well have decided not to generate code for it in the first place -- dead code can be optimized away entirely.

This question is pretty underspecified, anyway. What do you mean by "the program is read-only"? The source code, or the executable? Are we attacking it from inside the process at runtime, inside the process by changing the source code, outside the process by trying to invoke it in funny ways, ...?

If the compiler generated code for the function (i.e. it didn't get chopped by the dead code optimizer) and you have a debugger and debug symbols, just attach a debugger and tell it to find and invoke func().

If you want to exploit the code at runtime, you can cause a buffer overflow in gets(), and take control of the process from inside, but you still have to find func() so you can jump to it -- having the source code won't help you here, and nothing will help you here if the compiler didn't generate code for it.

Comment: Indeed, unless your compiler is utterly broken, `func` will not even exist in the emitted binary. So it cannot be called.

Comment: @R.. No, only the *call* to `func` will not exist. If the code compiled, then `func` was declared, amd *may* have been defined -- in which case its address can be stored as the return address on the stack by overflowing the `gets`. The address of `func` might have been obtained via `nm` if the executable wasn't stripped.

Comment: "If there are no other references to func(), the compiler may well have decided not to generate code for it in the first place" -- only if `func` is `static`; if it's global, the compiler can't eliminate it.

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting the return address to the `func()` call by overflowing `buffer`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Exploiting_stack_buffer_overflows

Comment: Pasting a link all by itself is not a good idea here, unless you add some comment around it to express your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have the source code, I would make the following edit and recompile:

```
-if(0) func();
+func();
```

---

Serious answer, there are thousands of ways of doing it (hacked environments, buffer overflows, etc), but the common pitfall is that a good compiler should optimize `if (0) {}` away. If that is the case there would be no way of executing `func()`. If not, then I would just start up my trusty debugger and jumping to the right spot.

Comment: You can't edit the source and recompile the program, you have to use tho original compiled program

Comment: You said `the program is read-only`, not the source.

Comment: "If that is the case there would be no way of executing func()" -- that simply isn't true. If `func` was compiled into the binary, it can be called by storing its address on the stack; that `if(0) func();` is simply misdirection.

Comment: @Jim Balter: If all occurences of `func()` are optimized away then `func` will simply not be linked into the binary, end of story. Since there was only one `func()`, if that gets optimized away then the `func` won't be linked in.

Comment: You don't seem to understand how C linkage works. If  foo.c defines a global function `func` and foo.o is linked into the executable, then the code for `func` will be included, regardless of whether there are any calls to it. "Since there was only one func()" -- sez who? There's no reason at all to think that's true ... not that it's relevant; only static functions are optimized away, and only with that optimization enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously, execute the famous `set 0=1` command before running your executable.

But seriously, this is way off-topic...